# Nginx unknown directive "if"

Tags: nginx, http-referer, nginx-location

On my Nginx server, in order to save time, I made etc/nginx/include.conf and put this line in etc/nginx/sites-available/site1.conf:

```
location / {
    include /etc/nginx/include.conf;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?page=$uri;
}
```

The content of include.conf :

```
if ($http_referer ~* (badreferers)) { 
        return 403; 
}
```

When testing the conf file, this error emerges:
[emerg] unknown directive "if" in /etc/nginx/include.conf:1

When I put the if statement directly in etc/nginx/sites-available/site1.conf, it doesn't give an error.

What could be wrong here?

Update:
`nginx -V` gives:

> nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu) built by gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu
>   4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) TLS SNI support enabled configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_spdy_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module

Comment: it may be spacemark-sensitive, so try to remove extra ones. `if ($http_referer ~* ...)`

Comment: hi, thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't change the problem when testing this.

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165976/nginx-emerg-unknown-directive-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled-example-com3 this thread solutions for bad characters?

Comment: Yes, I even retyped the whole statement just to be sure

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk did you compile nginx by yourself, or it's from an OS distro/repo or some other ready compiled sources? Please update your question and include the output of `nginx -V`.

Comment: It was a LEMP install on Digitalocean, updated with nginx -V

Comment: @C.A.Vuyk I don't see the `--without-http_rewrite_module` argument and that means that the nginx you have is compiled with `http_rewrite_module`. Nginx `return` is also part of `ngx_http_rewrite_module`. Can you try to use `return 403;` inside the `location` like this `location / { return 403; }` without `include` and `try_files` and see if the nginx configuration test returns any errors and the page returns a `403` status? If it does not pass the config test, then your nginx binaries do not have `ngx_http_rewrite_module` if it does passes the test, then there is something else going on.

Comment: Hi, it passes the test and when testing it returns a 403 status.

Comment: So, `nginx` is installed with `http_rewrite_module`. Please try to put the `if` directly inside the `location` before `try_files` without including a file and see what you'll get after testing the configuration.

Comment: Christos, I mentioned that in my question. Indeed when I put the if statement directly in etc/nginx/sites-available/site1.conf, in the location context, it doesn't give an error and works well. That's the strange thing about this all...

Comment: Yes, I have read it but I forgot about it. Btw, the `nginx` version you have is quite old and you should update to the latest `1.11` or the stable `1.10`. The latest versions may have bug fixes that address your problem.

Comment: Christos, this was tested by Alexander and he has found that this was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use old nginx version 1.4. On modern 1.10.2 your config works fine.

I've checked the sources of nginx. The "include" directive isn't just replaced with content of included file. It is processed differently depending on context. So there are definitely some restrictions of what you may put in included file. At least in your nginx version.
As [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include) says

> Included files should consist of syntactically correct directives and
>   blocks.

Answer (score 0):

**if** is part of http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#if . you will need to add the rewrite module into your nginx.

Or better us the official package from nginx them self

http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#stable

Comment: There is no directive to enable nginx `http_rewrite_module` but one to disable it and it is `--without-http_rewrite_module` which is not included to the nginx version the OP has. That's why I asked to see the `nginx -V` output. See OP's updated answer for the directives his nginx version uses.

Comment: Aleks, I don't think this is the problem. I use a lot of rewrites, also see comment of Christos below my question. The test returns a good 403.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have read it. Well I have saved your nginx -V output split it via perl and searched for rew. the rewrite module wasn't found. "perl -MData::Dumper -ane 'print Dumper(@F),"\n";' < /tmp/llll|egrep rew". I also see that you have --with-debug so please can you run nginx with debug log as described at http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: Debug log gives this:  2017/03/11 11:03:18 [emerg] 13364#0: unknown directive "if" in /etc/nginx/include.conf:1

Comment: Hm. Is this the real line or somehow obfuscated? "if ($http_referer ~* (badreferers)) { ...}'. What I mean is that '(badreferers)' are used as regex and '(' and ')' should be '\(' '\)'. Is it possible to use a younger version then the one of ' 04 Mar 2014' http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES-1.4 ?

Comment: It is the real line, however when it works I change 'badreferer' in some other words of course. I've changed it now in if ($http_referer ~* ('badreferer')) {return 403; } but with no luck. This is what you meant isn't it? I would rather not change the Nginx version because of this is a live server and I'm afraid of things breaking.

Comment: okay thanks. then you can also use this as test 'if ($http_referer ~* 'badreferer') {return 403; } ' without the brackets

Comment: Tried this also, no luck, accepted Alexanders answer, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have somewhere in nginx config files line like

```
include /etc/nginx/*.conf;
```

So your file */etc/nginx/include.conf* is included not only in */etc/nginx/sites-available/site1.conf* but somewehere else where "if" directive is invalid and you get error.

Comment: The only place this would be possible to include so it would interfere, would be in the file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf isn't it? There it is not included.

Comment: I recommend to make search with grep: grep -R "conf" /etc/nginx/* to get all files containing string "conf". Or just try to rename include.conf to include.inc and check if it helps.

Comment: Alexander, just did so, no hidden includes that may throw errors unfortunately...

Comment: If so than it may be just old nginx version. There were some limitations for include directive. If I remember correct included file could contain only blocks like location or server or just simple lines of directives without block. On modern 1.10.2 your config works fine.

Comment: ok, please give this as an answer then. I can't check this because I don't want to meddle with my nginx for it is a live server

Comment: If you add this as an answer I'll accept it and you can have the bonus

Comment: ok, I'll just check sources of nginx 1.4 to be completely sure.