# Simple Docker/Nginx Error - PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, docker, nginx

I'm building a PHP and Laravel docker multi-container application by following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c).

It's straight forward and I followed it accurately but I'm running into the following error when running `docker-compose up`:

```
database_1  | 2018-07-08 16:51:11 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
database_1  | Version: '5.6.40'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
app_1       | [08-Jul-2018 15:02:52] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
app_1       | [08-Jul-2018 16:51:10] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
web_1       | 2018/07/08 16:52:24 [emerg] 1#1: unknown directive "listen:" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
web_1       | nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "listen:" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2
see-number_web_1 exited with code 1
```

The following is my `web.dockerfile` that handles the web/nginx service:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

And this is the `vhost.conf` file which I'm using:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

---

Here's the entire `docker-compose.yml` file holding it all together:

```
version: '2'
services:

  # The Application
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  # The Database
  database:
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
        - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

---

I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21960803/6365534) that talks about hidden EOL characters but I've tried typing it out myself, and running it through [this tool](https://www.textfixer.com/tools/remove-line-breaks.php) in the same thread.

Any suggestions as to why I might be getting this error?

---

**Update 1**
As requested, I'm including the `docker history` for the web service image that's causing issues:

```
<user>:<project> <user>$ docker history see-number_web
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
5c0285cb9dd2        6 hours ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:4387275b028088cf9…   453B                
0346349a1a64        15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["nginx" "-g" "daemon…   0B                  
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 443/tcp 80/tcp        0B                  
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx…   22B                 
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp…   58.2MB              
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NGINX_VERSION=1.10.3-…   0B                  
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  MAINTAINER NGINX Docker M…   0B                  
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/bash"]            0B                  
<missing>           15 months ago       /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:4eedf861fb567fffb…   123MB
```

Comment: Nginx server blocks need to be contained within http blocks. Is that conf file being included by nginx.conf?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter considering I followed the tutorial accurately, could you please elaborate on what you mean, possibly with an example? And I believe my `web.dockerfile` is including it properly. Do you see a reason why it wouldn't be?

Answer (score 2):

As it clearly complains about "unknown directive "listen:" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:2". Something wrong in nginx container config.

To debug it more, I would manually run the web_1 container in intractive mode and should start looking at /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf file.

Else you just rebuild your nginx container.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to build that exact container in interactive mode. I know I'll build it by using: `docker-compose build web`. But how do I do this interactive mode that you're talking about, and what will it benefit?

Comment: Not to get confused (What i meant by interactive mode )If i am interested in troubleshooting more into the current error, then i would fire up the container from the image which is already created(web_1) and start checking at the nginx config file after opening up a bash session.

Comment: Some answers that I linked to in the question were talking about EOL (end of line) characters. Could there be anything besides that happening in your opinion? Also, I can't fire up the container because it exited with status `1`. I can get into the other containers, just not that one.

Comment: possibly yes, But cant confirm unless we see. Can you post your docker history for your image file?

Comment: I posted the `docker history <project>_web` but I don't believe this will be of much service because I directly pulled down the `nginx:1.10` image in my `web.dockerfile`, therefore I haven't edited it in any way. Is there any other diagnostic information I could provide?

Comment: would suggest you to double check your vhost.conf file. It must have a junk character or  EOL (end of line) characters which is causing this problem.Size should be 452B while it adds the config file in the end.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that may encounter weird errors during a process like this or similar to it:

I had to `docker rmi` any images that were associated with my `docker-compose.yml`. I believe some image was cached from earlier when it actually needed to be rebuilt. Changing files and running `docker-compose up` doesn't clear or rebuild anything - therefore deleting images and doing a full `docker-compose up` again worked.