# nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core

I am trying to setup Nginx to my ASPNET Core WebApi. But I keep running into errors.

When I try to check my Config I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-26-12-97:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have tried to look at the following issues:
[nginx: [emerg] "http" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643829/nginx-emerg-http-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled)
and
[nginx: [emerg] unknown directive " " in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example.com:3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165976/nginx-emerg-unknown-directive-in-etc-nginx-sites-enabled-example-com3)

my default config looks like the following:

```
server {
 listen 80;
 location / {
 proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 }
}
```

Installing Nginx and going to default Nginx server on port 80 works fine. But when I start to upload my own configs and make changes it breaks.

Steps:

```
sudo chown ubuntu:ubuntu /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

so I can use SCP to upload new default site

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i {pemFile} -qrp C:/path/. ubuntu@{hostname}:/etc/nginx/sites-available/
```

Both https://garywoodfine.com/deploying-net-core-application-to-aws-lightsail/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.0 seems pretty similar without any results.

Comment: To understand the cause, you need to see where the file is being included into the overall configuration. Possibly a missing closing `}` in the previous included file makes the `server` directive appear to be nested within the wrong block. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: ubuntu@ip-172-26-12-97:~$ sudo nginx -T      
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "server" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:1     
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed     
       
Is all I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. After letting this question be on Stackoverflow for some time I tried to spin up Virtual Machine on my computer. Create a config file with the exact same content. Copy paste from my Windows machine to my linux machine. Uploaded the file to my linux server and it worked.

So in short Windows screwed with the content of the file without I was able to see anything. I have uploaded a working version of the file here:
https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/topswagcode.dev/default

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue, i fixed by opening the nginx.conf with Notepad++ and convert it to ANSI

Format > Convert to ANSI

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. Later, I upload the configuration file by using Filezila and it worked.